# Create Customized Tokenizer for Stanford core NLP

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

am new baby to stanford NLP and have been using this from last few days and now stuck to my last step of the process.
When i use PTBTokenizer it breaks the sentence into words but what i want is that it should break sentence into either NamedEntities or Verbs so that i can use kind of dependency tree to rebuild sentence with direct kind of conclusions from whole sentence also it should also understand the same entity from entities.
Is that possible to customize tokenizer to achieve this? 
Your help is appriatiated.
Thanks in advance.

```
try{
     // Properties props = StringUtils.argsToProperties(args);

      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put("annotators",   "tokenize,ssplit");
      props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,lemma,pos,parse,ner");
      StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP();
      String sentence = "Kapil Puri, original promoter of Sparsh BPO, now owned by Blackstone controlled Intelenet, has decided to sell his residual stake of 12%.";

      Annotation doc = new Annotation(sentence);

      pipeline.annotate(doc);
      RelationExtractorAnnotator r = new RelationExtractorAnnotator(props);
      r.annotate(doc);

      for(CoreMap s: doc.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)){         
        System.out.println("For sentence :=>" + s.get(CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation.class));
        List<RelationMention> rls  = s.get(RelationMentionsAnnotation.class);
        for(RelationMention rl: rls){
          System.out.println(rl.toString());
        }
      }
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: care to add some sample code of what you have done so far?

Comment: @user1673091, it's unclear what you really want here. I don't think you want to tokenize — you should be using NER output if you want named entities, and the POS tagger output if you want to find verbs.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you cannot achieve this directly, even I faced the similar problem. Here I tried using the following procedure:
I applied the PTBTokenizer initially and then used NER and RegexNER over it, then using the results, I started merging the data with the help of consecutive NER Tags.

If two or more consecutive words have same tag, then I merged into a single word.